# How to get the Cache Event Key from Mule

Tags: caching, mule, anypoint-studio

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and have a mule managed store Caching Strategy that uses the default Event Key generation.

How can I get the value of this key in a flow?  Where is it stored?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the generator provides `SHA 256 hash` as a key if you don't provide a key generator expression in your cache.
ref:- https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/keygenerator/SHA256MuleEventKeyGenerator.java
This generators computes a `SHA 256 hash` of the ***current message*** bytes payload.

You can use the following example to get the list of cache key of your flow:-

```
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="cachingStrategy" doc:name="cachingStrategy">
   <managed-store storeName="myNonPersistentManagedObjectStore" maxEntries="-1" entryTTL="20000" expirationInterval="5000"/>
</ee:object-store-caching-strategy>

<flow name="keylist" doc:name="keylist">
         <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/getkeyvalue" doc:name="HTTP"/>
            <scripting:component doc:name="Initialise Database"> 
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                <scripting:text><![CDATA[
             def keyValues = [];
              for(a=0;a<muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObject("cachingStrategy").getStore().allKeys().size();a++)
               {
                     keyValues = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObject("cachingStrategy").getStore().allKeys().get(a);

                }

                if(keyValues.isEmpty())
                {
                 return "Key is either null or expired !!!";
                }
                else
                {
                 return "KeysList " + muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObject("cachingStrategy").getStore().allKeys().toString();
                }           

               ]]></scripting:text>

            </scripting:script>  
        </scripting:component>
       </flow>
```

Whenever you put some message in your cache, using the above flow you can get all the list of the **default cache keys values** which the cache scope provide as `SHA 256 hash` as default